# Is it possible to return Salesforce to previous version?

Tags: apex, aura, production, release

We found that the production org of one of our clients was updated to Winter'21 today.

After this uest users can't log in to home website (made of Aura components).
Here is what cause problems: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_networks_reduce_object_perms.htm

Is it possible to return version to previous?
If not, what can resolve those problems?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to return to a previous release of Salesforce.

You'll have to rebuild or revise any functionality that relies on the Guest Site User being granted these permissions.

Note that the process of removing permissions from the Guest Site User has been in progress for multiple releases, is called out in release notes weeks prior to the release, and it paralleled in sandboxes during the early phase of the release rollout, where org owners have a chance to test and remediate this functionality.

Comment: Rebuilding could resolve problems?

Comment: @NonameJavaNoob By "rebuild", I mean that you will have to modify your customizations to work in the new permissions regime.